# For which natural numbers n is the number $s^n+1$ divisible by $10$?

Tags: number-theory

For which natural numbers $n$ is the number $s^n+1$ divisible by $10$?

I want to take case of the form $10k, 10k+1, ..., 10k+9$. But I am not sure which number $s$ or $n$ to use for cases or if I am suppose to do it for?

Comment: what conditions are you putting on $s$?

Comment: To get ya started: $3^2+1=10$.

Comment: @symplectomorphic there are no conditions on s

Comment: so $s$ need not even be an integer?

Comment: @symplectomorphic nope. s doesn't need to be an integer.

Comment: I think the problem is missing context. where did you find this problem?

Comment: If $s$ is not an integer, the resulting expression is entirely at $s$ will. Besides from positivity, $n$ has no opinion here.

Comment: If you're allowing non-integers, it doesn't make sense to talk about divisibility, does it?

Comment: @Cadenza The obvious solution is to take divisible by 10 to mean "is an integer that is divisible by 10". But if one allows non-integers the problem is easily reduced back to the integer case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** $s^n +1 \equiv 0 \mod 10 \iff s^n \equiv 9 \mod 10 \iff s^n$ has a $9$ for its unit digit.